# How do I prove that if $n$ is a quadratic residue of $m > 2$ then $n^{\varphi(m)/2}\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Please, give me an idea of how to get started.

Comment: Is $m$ prime? For $m$ prime, this is [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).

Comment: Do you mean $n$ instead of $r$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, n. Sorry

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a full statement of the problem you want help with.  Using the title alone to carry this burden handcuffs your explanation and invites confusion on the part of your Readers.

Answer (score 4):

You must be using the convention that a quadratic residue mod $m$ is coprime to $m$: your statement is certainly not true if $r$ is not coprime to $m$.  If $r$ is such a quadratic residue, $r \equiv x^2 \mod m$ for some $x$, which is also
coprime to $m$.  Then $r^{\varphi(m)/2} \equiv x^{\varphi(m)} \equiv 1 \mod m$.